# Facebook debugger not reading OG tags

Tags: facebook, facebook-sharer

I am creating a page for a largely static website. This page is generating customized URLs for Facebook Share buttons. I am trying to share individual images or MP4 videos on the page, not the page itself. The _GET info in the URL is determined by the link clicked and PHP modifies the OG tags with the relevant info. I am trying to set it up so the share preview will show a thumbnail along with the title and description.

On the page itself the image share links work fine but the video share links produce a 403 error even though the links are correct and I can open the videos manually with no problem. When I try to view the "*See exactly what our scraper sees for your URL*" link on the Debugger page it just shows a blank page.

Facebook debugger receives URL's like

https://checkthenshare.ca/share-dev.php?image=covid-Check-First-th.png&video=MS_Social_CFSA.mp4

It return's errors like,

*Inferred Property : The 'og:image' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.
Missing Properties : The following required properties are missing: og:url, og:type, og:title, og:image, og:description, fb:app_id*

The OG code that is being produced looks okay to me but I don't have a lot of experience with it.

```
    <meta property="og:url" content="https://checkthenshare.ca/img/stories/MS_Social_CFSA.mp4" />
    <meta property="og:title" content="Check first. Then Share." />        
    <meta property="og:description" content="Passing on false content can be like passing on COVID-19 itself. And that can be deadly. Before you share, pause, check the source, and make sure it&apos;s legit. Check First. Share After. https://checkthenshare.ca" />
    <meta property="og:site_name" content="Check first. Then Share." />
    <meta property="og:type" content="video.other" />  
    <meta property="og:image:url" content="https://checkthenshare.ca/img/covid-Check-First-th.png" /> 
    <meta property="og:image" content="https://checkthenshare.ca/img/covid-Check-First-th.png" />
    <meta property="og:image:width" content="540" />
    <meta property="og:image:height" content="960" />         
    <meta property="og:locale" content="en_CA" />
    <meta property="og:video:type" content="video/mp4" />
    <meta property="og:video:url" content="https://checkthenshare.ca/img/stories/MS_Social_CFSA.mp4" />
    <meta property="og:video" content="https://checkthenshare.ca/img/stories/MS_Social_CFSA.mp4" />
    <meta property="og:video:width" content="1080" />
    <meta property="og:video:height" content="1920" />
```

I am hoping some hawk-eyed person can spot some error in my tags. I am going crossed eyed staring at them.

Thanks!

Comment: You set og:url to `https://checkthenshare.ca/img/stories/MS_Social_CFSA.mp4`. Facebook will treat that as a redirect and go and fetch og-tags from that URL.

Comment: Thanks! That's cleared up the errors and reading the tags but it's just showing/sharing the thumbnail now, not the mp4.